# Area of a triangle (3 points given)

Tags: java, math, equation, area

Hello I am trying to write a java program that takes three points (a,b, and c) and finds the area of a triangle.  I am getting stuck because I don't know the coordinates of the points (they will be given later in a tester class).  Should i write the code to convert the points to cartesian coordinates and then use those to find the area?  Im really stuck on this so any suggestions will help.  Thanks.

Comment: "Should i write the code to convert the points to cartesian coordinates" What in your view is the difference between a point and cartesian coordinates?

Comment: @weston the points I have are Point a, Point b, Point C.  I don't know how to convert this to say (Ax,Ay),(Bx,By).  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Tim thank you, thats exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: No it makes no sense to convert as a point already has X and Y parts.

Answer (score 2):

A compact and nicely symmetric way to remember the area formula is

```
              [ 1 a.x a.y ]
area = 0.5*det[ 1 b.x b.y ]
              [ 1 c.x c.y ]
```

This will give a signed area, negative if the order of the vertices is clockwise.  For implementations one of course simplifies the determinant by row and column operations.